# xcode ios 5 Master-Detail Application with Storyboard

Tags: tableview, master-detail, uisplitview, detailview

I have one question about Master-Detail Application.

It's possible to add in storyboard a second and third DetailView?

I will that when i click in the tableview on the first button he show me detailview1 and when i click on the second button he show me the second DetailView and...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial: [Beginning Storyboards in iOS 5 Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) which you can use to understand Master-Detail View apps as it goes through from Single View to `UITableViewController` implementation.